# Character pointer access

Tags: c++, character

I wanted to access character pointer ith element. Below is the sample code

```
string a_value = "abcd";
char *char_p=const_cast<char *>(a_value.c_str());

if(char_p[2] == 'b') //Is this safe to use across all platform?
{
  //do soemthing
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong with `a_value[2]` ?

Comment: Why do you need `const_cast` here?

Comment: @BoBTFish It's not, as long as `a_char` isn't used to actually modify the string. It's still a really, really bad idea.

Comment: c_str returns const char * that's why need const_cast

Comment: My question was  whether using parenthesis [] is allowed for char * because is a not a character arrays

Comment: You don't need `const_cast` - you need to declare `char_p` as `const char*`. In fact, as Quentin noted, you don't need `char_p` at all.

Comment: Sorry guys typo errors

Comment: It's a pretty strong clue, you are given something `const`, then you ditch the `const` and change that thing, you are doing something wrong. In this case, the clue is correct. This is not allowed.

Comment: @BoBTFish I'm being more optimistic than you, and for now that string is untouched. A huge, blinking warning sign is needed though ;)

Comment: @Quentin True. Sorry, I'm getting carried away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array accessors `[]` are allowed for pointer types, and result in defined and predictable behaviors if the offset inside `[]` refers to valid memory.

```
const char* ptr = str.c_str();
if (ptr[2] == '2') {
    ...
}
```

Is correct on all platforms *if* the length of `str` is 3 characters or more.

---

In general, if you are not mutating the `char*` you are looking at, it best to avoid a `const_cast` and work with a `const char*`. Also note that `std::string` provides `operator[]` which means that you do not need to call `.c_str()` on `str` to be able to index into it and look at a `char`. This will similarly be correct on all platforms *if* the length of `str` is 3 characters or more. If you do not know the length of the string in advance, use `std::string::at(size_t pos)`, which performs bound checking and throws an `out_of_range` exception if the check fails.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the ith element in a `std::string` using its `operator[]()` like this:

```
std::string a_value = "abcd";
if (a_value[2] == 'b')
{
  // do stuff
}
```

If you use a C++11 conformant `std::string` implementation you can also use:

```
std::string a_value = "abcd";
char const * p = &a_value[0];
// or char const * p = a_value.data();
// or char const * p = a_value.c_str();
// or char * p = &a_value[0];
```

> **21.4.1/5**
>
> The char-like objects in a basic_string object shall be stored contiguously.
>
> **21.4.7.1/1: c_str() / data()**
>
> Returns: A pointer p such that `p + i == &operator[](i)` for each i in [0,size()].

Comment: a_value.c_str() is not necessarily the same as &a_value[0]. The wording of the standard is subtle, and allows for the two different calls to return different memory references/addresses.

Comment: @RichardHodges It is the same, after all. See my standard quote. `c_str()` is required to return a pointer such that `p + 0 == &operator[](0)` meaning `a_value.c_str() == &a_value[0]`.

Comment: I see. I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

The question is essentially about querying characters in a string safely.

```
const char* a = a_value.c_str();
```

is safe unless some other operation modifies the string after it. If you can guarantee that no other code performs a modification prior to using a, then you have safely retrieved a pointer to a null-terminated string of characters.

```
char* a = const_cast<char *>(a_value.c_str());
```

is never safe. You have yielded a pointer to memory that is writeable. However, that memory was never designed to be written to. There is no guarantee that writing to that memory will actually modify the string (and actually no guarantee that it won't cause a core dump). It's undefined behaviour - absolutely unsafe.
reference here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str

addressing `a[2]` is safe provided you can prove that all possible code paths ensure that a represents a pointer to memory longer than 2 chars.

If you want safety, use either:

```
auto ch = a_string.at(2); // will throw an exception if a_string is too short.
```

or

```
if (a_string.length() > 2) {
    auto ch = a_string[2];
}
else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: _"is never safe", "it's undefined behaviour"_ Not true. The cast itself is perfectly well-defined.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit respectfully, I believe you have misquoted me. What I am conveying is that the standard does not guarantee that the string yielded by c_str() is even at the same memory address as the storage in std::string. It also does not guarantee that the memory is writable. Thus writing to it is undefined behaviour. There is no reason that it should not cause a segfault.

Comment: The OP's _not_ writing to it. There is no _inherent_ non-safety and no undefined behaviour in the question's code. Either you're answering some other question or I have not misquoted you. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The OP has yielded a 'pointer to mutable memory' pointing to memory that is not mutable. He is a hair's breadth away from stepping on a landmine. I have not stated that he *is writing* to the memory. I have warned him that to do so invites disaster. One might say I have answered the wider question around his question in the hope that he can avoid some otherwise inevitable disasters. :)

Comment: Again, you stated that the OP's code "is never safe" and "it's undefined behaviour". I'm not saying the OP's code is a good idea but you're not telling the truth about it.

Comment: casting away the const of the result of a call to a_string.c_str() is certainly never safe. The resulting pointer to mutable chars is unsafe. There is absolutely no reason to do it, and the outcome only has downsides. Given that, I think the wording of my answer is reasonable. If you disagree, feel free to re-word it to some form of words you prefer.

Comment: There _are_ reasons to do it. If you work with old C APIs then you often have no choice but to do it, and rely on the documentation promising that it won't mutate the pointee. It's never ideal, but to outright state that the cast itself is unsafe is simply incorrect. I guess we're talking about different meanings of the word "unsafe".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77160/discussion-between-richard-hodges-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Answer (score 0):

Everyone explained very well for most how it's safe, but i'd like to extend a bit if that's ok.

Since you're in C++, and you're using a string, you can simply do the following to access a caracter (and you won't have any trouble, and you still won't have to deal with cstrings in cpp :

```
  std::string a_value = "abcd";
  std::cout << a_value.at(2);
```

Which is in my opinion a better option rather than going out of the way.
string::at will return a char & or a const char&  depending on your string object. (In this case, a const char &)

Answer (score -1):

In this case you can treat char* as an array of chars (C-string). Parenthesis is allowed.